# Does revoke operation wait a consume process to finish in Kafka rebalance?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

For example if I have a long running process in one of my KafkaConsumer. (Let's say takes 1 hour to finish.) If rebalance is triggered ,does revoke operation for this consumer wait until this consumer consume (process) message that has started to process before rebalance?

So is it possible to just because of this rebalance takes too much time?

Or revoke operation is done immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new Java consumers default time is 5 minutes for rebalancing and before the rebalance broker will remove that consumer from group and invoke the rebalancing, It will just remove that thread but not terminated (So consumer will process all the records that it started and after finishing it will die)

**If no heartbeats are received by the broker before the expiration of this session timeout, then the broker will remove this consumer from the group and initiate a rebalance.**

**If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.**

> The new Java Consumer now supports heart beating from a background thread. There is a new configuration max.poll.interval.ms which controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer will proactively leave the group (5 minutes by default). The value of the configuration request.timeout.ms must always be larger than max.poll.interval.ms because this is the maximum time that a JoinGroup request can block on the server while the consumer is rebalancing, so we have changed its default value to just above 5 minutes.

Comment: I know the conditions that trigger rebalance. I just want to know when rebalance starts and all KafkaConsumers start to be revoked, will this revoke process wait for a long consume process for some KafkaConsumer? I mean can KafkaConsumer which is consuming a message at that time can be revoked immediately or kafka waits before revoking this KafkaConsumer?

Comment: If consumer failed to make subsequent poll in 5 minutes, then immediately consumer is removed from group, broker will not wait for any particular time

Comment: What if another consumer (c1) leads to rebalance (cannot send heartbeat or didn't poll() for a long time ()). At that point; all the consumers should be revoked. At that point consumer c2 is still consuming message. Does Kafka waits c2 to process message or revoke it immediately too? This is my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are overthinking it, during rebalance kafka will remove the un responding consumer threads and share that partitions between the alive consumer threads @H.Ç.T